# How to stop CACHE instance from Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, cache

I want to restart CACHE(database that I am using) Instance from shell script. What I did is created a function in the shell script named resatrt_cache.

```
restart_cache()
{
 ccontrol stop instancename restart
}
```

This command is running but the control goes to cache and while stopping cache it get stuck to this question

```
**Do you want to broadcast a message to anyone? No =>**
```

How can I pass the value here through shell script

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that it takes input from stdin, and you want to answer "no":

```
restart_cache() {
    ccontrol stop instancename restart << EOF
no
EOF
}
```

Note: the indentation is important.

If you want to answer "no" to any and all prompts, you can use `yes` instead:

```
restart_cache() {
    yes no | ccontrol stop instancename restart
}
```

If you'd rather accept the defaults (and the program takes a line feed to mean that), use `yes ''`.